# Json file with Authorization for POST

Tags: post, botframework, postman, bots, microsoft-teams

Im currently trying to send a message from Teams to a bot.

If I'm sending the message via `Postman` the bot receives the message.

[image]

When I'm trying to send a message from Teams the bot does not receive the message.

I assume that I have made an mistake in my `json` where my Authorization is. Can anyone tell me if my `header` is correct or where my mistake is?

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to connect the bot to Teams?

Comment: I send a message card as a json to teams with the bot-url as a target.

Comment: So basically a webhook is send to Microsoft Teams where I can enter a text and then send the text to the url seen in the first screenshot. The webhook has the header you see.

Comment: Could you post the code on how you are trying to send a message from Teams to the bot?

Comment: I could see that you are using Direct Line APIs. Please take a look at [Bot Framework REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) if you want to work with Microsoft Teams channel. Do you want to notify user on certain events? Please take a look at [Proactive messaging for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive).